# is there a way to re-render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have written an API in which I am rescuing from all StandardError. Incase of any StandardError, I send an exception email and render json with error message.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    rescue_from StandardError, with: :respond_with_error
    def respond_with_error(e)
        ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(e)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render json: {error: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity, content_type: 'application/json' }
            format.json { render json: {error: e.message}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        User.transaction do
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            authorize @user
            @user.save!
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
        end
    end
end
```

This works great except when the exception is raised from **render :show** in **UserController#create**. As then when I again render json with error message from **respond_with_error** in **ApplicationController**, it raises double render exception cause render has already been called in controller.

Is there a way to override/dismiss the initial render call?

ruby 2.1.8

rails 4.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the rescue block in the action itself.

```
 def create
    User.transaction do
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      authorize @user
      @user.save!
    end

    flash.now[:success] = "successfully updated"
    redirect_to @user and return 

  rescue StandardError => e
    respond_with_error(e)
  end
```

Just use redirect_to @user to render show page.

Comment: I want to avoid adding the rescue in each action of each controller and it wouldnt change anything.

Regarding the redirection, my rails app is an API so the client app expects the created object in response.

Comment: In that case just render :json => { status: created, user_object: @user } and return is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without looking at any code. But in general DoubleRenderException can be avoided with return, i.e

```
render :json => response_hash and return
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have added the code. As you can see I need to dismiss the initial render which caused the exception and then render a json with error message.